# Green's theorem and 'simple regions'

Tags: plane-curves, surface-integrals, greens-theorem

I'm looking through at my notes and couldn't understand why, in the notes below, there is a need to compute the curve C2 and C4.

[image]

It's hard to see why isn't computing C1 and C3 a sufficient condition.